# Downsides for not implementing _read in stream.Readable

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, coffeescript

I have asynchronous data source I'd like to give `stream.Readable` interface. However, this data source has no concept of 'reading' from it — when there is data for me, I only receive an event, no buffer is maintained.

So, is there any drawback in using following implementation?

```
stream = require 'stream'

class Wrapper extends stream.Readable
    constructor: (@resource) ->
        # call stream.Readable constructor
        super

        # when message from resource arrives
        @resource.on 'message', (message) =>
            # just push it into read queue
            @push message

        # when resource is closed
        @resource.on 'close', =>
            # indicate there will be nothing more to read
            @push null

    _read: (size) ->
        # no-op
```

E.g. if `_read` method is empty, and data is being pushed into read queue eventually on per-message basis, am I breaking anything?

Answer (score 1):

The `_read()` method is there to notify you that the stream can handle more data (e.g. the internal buffer hasn't hit the highWaterMark yet). You're free to ignore it of course.

However you should at least handle backpressure appropriately: if `push()` returns `false`, you should stop pushing until `_read()` is called or 'drain' is emitted.

Comment: What if I can't stop pushing — if I'll stop listening for `message` event for some time, messages arrived in that time interval would be lost, and if I'll buffer them myself and then `push` all at once, how would be that different from buffering it with stream core?